# adjusting the distance between numbers on console

Tags: c++

I've made a program to create the pascal's triangle. the program takes number of rows as input and displays the triangle on the console. I've used the `setw()` function to set the distance between numbers. it's of for unit single digits but when the numbers get greater than 10,the width is not being adjusted properly,right now I've :

```
if(P<10){
   std::cout << P ;
   std::cout <<std::setw(2);
}

if(P>=10){
   std::cout<<std::setw(3) << P ;
   std::cout<<std::setw(2);
}
```

here's the ouput from the console:

```
                      1
                     1 1
                    1 2 1
                   1 3 3 1
                  1 4 6 4 1
                 1 5 10 10 5 1
                1 6 15 20 15 6 1
               1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
              1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
             1 9 36 84126126 84 36 9 110
```

I want it to appear like a proper triangle,Could someone help me out please???

Comment: What do you mean with "the width is not being adjusted properly"? Can you show some actual output versus some wanted output? And maybe create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us some complete code?

Comment: As for copying from a Windows console window, on the top-left icon menu there is an entry called "Mark" or similar, select that, mark (with the mouse) the text you want, and select copy in the menu.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,I know that and have tried it many a time but that trick seems to work only once in a blue moon!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,I was trying that very thing to show the ouput on my console...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,added the output

Comment: Please learn to intent your code.. Please

Comment: @Krishnabhadra,please explain what proper indentation means,coz as far as I see the code is readable!!!

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong since you don't show more code, but remember that the width you set with [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) is reset on next output operation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,well I've shown the part where I am displaying the ouput on the console!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you read e.g. [this reference of `std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) you will see

> The width property of the stream will be reset to zero (meaning "unspecified") if any of the following functions are called

And then goes on to list basically all output operators.

This means that when you do

```
std::cout <<std::setw(2);
```

the width will only be set for the *next* output operation. If you do any kind of output after that the width will be reset to zero.

Comment: forgive me but I am still confused:(

Comment: @AaymanKhalid If you do e.g. `std::cout << std::setw(3) << 1 << 9;` only the first number will be justified, the output operation after the first number will cause the justification to be reset.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg,and what if I do `std::cout<<std::setw(2)<<1<<std::setw(2);`?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid Then the next number you print should be adjusted to two characters.

Comment: @AaymanKhalid Then I would say this question is very hard (if not impossible) to answer without you showing more code.